# D3 v4 Grid: How do I bind the data properly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been working on a square grid in d3 to show color-coded reasons for 78 individual events. When loaded, I only have one black square show up, it seems that the d.x and d.y positioning are not coming through and I'm not entirely sure why.

```js
d3.tsv("platform.tsv", function(data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].report_num);
        console.log(data[i].platform_medium);
    }

    var platformData = getWords(data);
    var squareSize = 20;
    var squarePad =5;
    var numPerRow = width / (squareSize + squarePad);
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60};
    var width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 520 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    function getWords(data) {
        return data.map(function (d, i) {
            // what category is this report?
            d.platform_medium = d.platform_medium;
            // sequential of report number
            d.report_num = +d.report_num;

            // positioning for square visual
            // stored here to make it easier
            // to keep track of.
            d.col = i % numPerRow;
            d.x = d.col * (squareSize + squarePad);
            d.row = Math.floor(i / numPerRow);
            d.y = d.row * (squareSize + squarePad);
            return d;
        });
    }

    var gridvis = d3.select("#chart2")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var gridFill7 = gridvis.append("defs")
                           .append("linearGradient")
                           .attr("id", "gridFill7")
                           .attr("x1", "0%")
                           .attr("x2", "0%")
                           .attr("y1", "100%")
                           .attr("y2", "0%");

    gridFill7.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#0652DD");

    gridFill7.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#C4E538");

    var gridFill8 = gridvis.append("defs")
                           .append("linearGradient")
                           .attr("id", "gridFill8")
                           .attr("x1", "0%")
                           .attr("x2", "0%")
                           .attr("y1", "100%")
                           .attr("y2", "0%");

    gridFill8.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#0652DD");

    gridFill8.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#EE5A24");


    // square grid
    // @v4 Using .merge here to ensure
    // new and old data have same attrs applied
    var squares = gridvis.selectAll('.square').data(platformData, function (d) { return d.report_num; });

    var squaresE = squares.enter()
                          .append('rect')
                          .classed('square', true);

    var squares = squares.merge(squaresE)
                         .attr('width', squareSize)
                         .attr('height', squareSize)
                         .attr('fill', '#fff')
                         .classed('fill-square', function (d) { return d.platform_medium; })
                         .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x;})
                         .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y;})
                         .attr('opacity', 0);


    function highlightGrid() {
        gridvis.selectAll('.fill-square')
               .transition()
               .duration(800)
               .attr('opacity', 1.0)
               .attr('fill', function (d) { 
                    if (d.platform_medium===1) {return "#0652DD";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===2) {return "#9980FA";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===3) {return "#C4E538";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===4) {return "#ED4C67";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===5) {return "#F79F1F";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===6) {return "#EE5A24";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===7) {return "url(#gridfill7)";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===8) {return "url(#gridfill8)";}

                });
    }

    highlightGrid();

});
```

Below is my sample data. Would appreciate someone with more experience than me taking a look :)

```
report_num  covid_related   platform_medium
1   0   1
2   0   1
3   0   1
4   0   1
5   0   1
6   0   3
7   0   1
8   0   3
9   0   1
10  0   3
11  0   1
12  0   3
13  1   2
14  1   1
15  1   3
16  1   1
17  1   1
18  1   1
19  1   1
20  1   1
21  1   1
22  1   1
23  1   1
24  0   1
25  0   7
26  1   1
27  1   1
28  1   1
29  1   1
30  1   1
31  1   1
32  1   1
33  1   1
34  1   1
35  1   1
36  0   1
37  0   1
38  0   2
39  0   7
40  1   1
41  1   1
42  1   1
43  1   1
44  1   1
45  1   1
46  0   5
47  0   5
48  0   1
49  0   1
50  0   1
51  0   1
52  1   1
53  1   1
54  1   1
55  0   1
56  0   5
57  0   1
58  0   1
59  0   1
60  0   1
61  0   7
62  0   1
63  0   1
64  0   1
65  0   1
66  0   1
67  1   5
68  1   1
69  1   1
70  1   3
71  1   3
72  1   1
73  1   1
74  1   7
75  1   8
76  1   1
77  1   4
78  1   2
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues causing problems. If you inspect the page you'll see that you have appended all the rectangles, but the x,y properties are NaN. If we backtrack that, we see we have an undefined value in `numPerRow`:

```
var platformData = getWords(data);
...
var numPerRow = width / (squareSize + squarePad);
...
var width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right;
```

Neither `width` or `numPerRow` have been defined when you call `getWords`, both of which `getWords` requires. Further, `width` isn't defined when you define `numPerRow`, so `numPerRow` should also be undefined, which means in `getWords` we assigning `undefined` to d.x and d.y, which means all rectangles get appended to the same location: [0,0] (within the parent `g`).

Fixing this we ensure `width` is defined before `numPerRow` and `getWords` is called after  both of the other two are defined. Now we have an arrangement of rectangles (I've also modified the translate on the parent `g` so the top left rectangle isn't in the middle of the screen):

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre").remove().text());


   
    var squareSize = 20;
    var squarePad =5;
   
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60};
    var width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 520 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     var numPerRow = width / (squareSize + squarePad);

    function getWords(data) {
        return data.map(function (d, i) {
            // what category is this report?
            d.platform_medium = d.platform_medium;
            // sequential of report number
            d.report_num = +d.report_num;

            // positioning for square visual
            // stored here to make it easier
            // to keep track of.
            d.col = i % numPerRow;
            d.x = d.col * (squareSize + squarePad);
            d.row = Math.floor(i / numPerRow);
            d.y = d.row * (squareSize + squarePad);
            return d;
        });
    }
    
    var platformData = getWords(data);
    

    var gridvis = d3.select("#chart2")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var gridFill7 = gridvis.append("defs")
                           .append("linearGradient")
                           .attr("id", "gridFill7")
                           .attr("x1", "0%")
                           .attr("x2", "0%")
                           .attr("y1", "100%")
                           .attr("y2", "0%");

    gridFill7.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#0652DD");

    gridFill7.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#C4E538");

    var gridFill8 = gridvis.append("defs")
                           .append("linearGradient")
                           .attr("id", "gridFill8")
                           .attr("x1", "0%")
                           .attr("x2", "0%")
                           .attr("y1", "100%")
                           .attr("y2", "0%");

    gridFill8.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#0652DD");

    gridFill8.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#EE5A24");


    // square grid
    // @v4 Using .merge here to ensure
    // new and old data have same attrs applied
    var squares = gridvis.selectAll('.square').data(platformData, function (d) { return d.report_num; });

    var squaresE = squares.enter()
                          .append('rect')
                          .classed('square', true);

    var squares = squares.merge(squaresE)
                         .attr('width', squareSize)
                         .attr('height', squareSize)
                         .attr('fill', '#fff')
                         .classed('fill-square', function (d) { return d.platform_medium; })
                         .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x;})
                         .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y;})
                         .attr('opacity', 0);


    function highlightGrid() {
        gridvis.selectAll('.fill-square')
               .transition()
               .duration(800)
               .attr('opacity', 1.0)
               .attr('fill', function (d) { 
                    if (d.platform_medium===1) {return "#0652DD";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===2) {return "#9980FA";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===3) {return "#C4E538";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===4) {return "#ED4C67";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===5) {return "#F79F1F";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===6) {return "#EE5A24";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===7) {return "url(#gridfill7)";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===8) {return "url(#gridfill8)";}

                });
    }

    highlightGrid();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart2"></div>
<pre>report_num,covid_related,platform_medium
1,0,1
2,0,1
3,0,1
4,0,1
5,0,1
6,0,3
7,0,1
8,0,3
9,0,1
10,0,3
11,0,1
12,0,3
13,1,2
14,1,1
15,1,3
16,1,1
17,1,1
18,1,1
19,1,1
20,1,1
21,1,1
22,1,1
23,1,1
24,0,1
25,0,7
26,1,1
27,1,1
28,1,1
29,1,1
30,1,1
31,1,1
32,1,1
33,1,1
34,1,1
35,1,1
36,0,1
37,0,1
38,0,2
39,0,7
40,1,1
41,1,1
42,1,1
43,1,1
44,1,1
45,1,1
46,0,5
47,0,5
48,0,1
49,0,1
50,0,1
51,0,1
52,1,1
53,1,1
54,1,1
55,0,1
56,0,5
57,0,1
58,0,1
59,0,1
60,0,1
61,0,7
62,0,1
63,0,1
64,0,1
65,0,1
66,0,1
67,1,5
68,1,1
69,1,1
70,1,3
71,1,3
72,1,1
73,1,1
74,1,7
75,1,8
76,1,1
77,1,4
78,1,2</pre>
```

But, the rectangles don't have any fill. This is because when you process the data you leave d.platform_medium as a string:

```
  d.platform_medium = d.platform_medium;
```

And when filling the rectangles, you use `===`, and "4" !== 4. We can use `==` or convert the strings to numbers. I do the latter below:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre").remove().text());


   
    var squareSize = 20;
    var squarePad =5;
   
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60};
    var width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 520 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     var numPerRow = width / (squareSize + squarePad);

    function getWords(data) {
        return data.map(function (d, i) {
            // what category is this report?
            d.platform_medium = +d.platform_medium;
            // sequential of report number
            d.report_num = +d.report_num;

            // positioning for square visual
            // stored here to make it easier
            // to keep track of.
            d.col = i % numPerRow;
            d.x = d.col * (squareSize + squarePad);
            d.row = Math.floor(i / numPerRow);
            d.y = d.row * (squareSize + squarePad);
            return d;
        });
    }
    
    var platformData = getWords(data);
    

    var gridvis = d3.select("#chart2")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var gridFill7 = gridvis.append("defs")
                           .append("linearGradient")
                           .attr("id", "gridFill7")
                           .attr("x1", "0%")
                           .attr("x2", "0%")
                           .attr("y1", "100%")
                           .attr("y2", "0%");

    gridFill7.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#0652DD");

    gridFill7.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#C4E538");

    var gridFill8 = gridvis.append("defs")
                           .append("linearGradient")
                           .attr("id", "gridFill8")
                           .attr("x1", "0%")
                           .attr("x2", "0%")
                           .attr("y1", "100%")
                           .attr("y2", "0%");

    gridFill8.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#0652DD");

    gridFill8.append("stop")
             .attr("offset", "50%")
             .style("stop-color", "#EE5A24");


    // square grid
    // @v4 Using .merge here to ensure
    // new and old data have same attrs applied
    var squares = gridvis.selectAll('.square').data(platformData, function (d) { return d.report_num; });

    var squaresE = squares.enter()
                          .append('rect')
                          .classed('square', true);

    var squares = squares.merge(squaresE)
                         .attr('width', squareSize)
                         .attr('height', squareSize)
                         .attr('fill', '#fff')
                         .classed('fill-square', function (d) { return d.platform_medium; })
                         .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x;})
                         .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y;})
                         .attr('opacity', 0);


    function highlightGrid() {
        gridvis.selectAll('.fill-square')
               .transition()
               .duration(800)
               .attr('opacity', 1.0)
               .attr('fill', function (d) { 
                    if (d.platform_medium===1) {return "#0652DD";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===2) {return "#9980FA";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===3) {return "#C4E538";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===4) {return "#ED4C67";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===5) {return "#F79F1F";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===6) {return "#EE5A24";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===7) {return "url(#gridfill7)";}
                    else if (d.platform_medium===8) {return "url(#gridfill8)";}

                });
    }

    highlightGrid();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart2"></div>
<pre>report_num,covid_related,platform_medium
1,0,1
2,0,1
3,0,1
4,0,1
5,0,1
6,0,3
7,0,1
8,0,3
9,0,1
10,0,3
11,0,1
12,0,3
13,1,2
14,1,1
15,1,3
16,1,1
17,1,1
18,1,1
19,1,1
20,1,1
21,1,1
22,1,1
23,1,1
24,0,1
25,0,7
26,1,1
27,1,1
28,1,1
29,1,1
30,1,1
31,1,1
32,1,1
33,1,1
34,1,1
35,1,1
36,0,1
37,0,1
38,0,2
39,0,7
40,1,1
41,1,1
42,1,1
43,1,1
44,1,1
45,1,1
46,0,5
47,0,5
48,0,1
49,0,1
50,0,1
51,0,1
52,1,1
53,1,1
54,1,1
55,0,1
56,0,5
57,0,1
58,0,1
59,0,1
60,0,1
61,0,7
62,0,1
63,0,1
64,0,1
65,0,1
66,0,1
67,1,5
68,1,1
69,1,1
70,1,3
71,1,3
72,1,1
73,1,1
74,1,7
75,1,8
76,1,1
77,1,4
78,1,2</pre>
```

*I've use d3.csvParse and a pre to hold the data (instead of d3.tsv) so it can fit in a snippet - otherwise, all changes to the code in the question are documented above*

Comment: Thank so much! that worked! Right now I have to enclose the whole visualization code within the d3.tsv function. Is there a way to isolate the data on it's own?